# How do i iterate over every line, and for each one append the result in a list?

Tags: python

I have a text that contains multiple lines, like:

```
roses are red
violets are blue
I'm trying to learn python 
please don't be rude
```

I would like to count every vowel in the text and store the vowel of every line in a list with a sequence:

```
open (file) as text
vowels = [aeiouy]
line = text.splitlines
point = 0
final_list = []

for line in text:
if line in vowels 
point = point +1
final_list.append(point)
```

expected:

```
[5, 6, 6, 7]
```

what happens?

```
0
```

Comment: Welcome. Your code doesn't run and we can't use it to troubleshoot. Please re-format it so we can run it and recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating through every character of each line, you may want to do that. Also, since you want each vowel to be a separate character, your vowel list should be something like `vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']`.
Maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
for line in text:
    for character in line:
        if character in vowels:
            point = point + 1
    final_list.append(point)
    point = 0
```